# Show that $B_1^{d_1}(0) $ is open in $(C[0,1], d_\infty)$ but $B_1^{d_\infty}(0)$ is not open in $(C[0,1],d_1)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that $B_1^{d_1}(0) $ is open in $(C[0,1], d_\infty)$ but $B_1^{d_\infty}(0)$ is not open in $(C[0,1],d_1)$

I am clueless on this one.

While proving first part,
if I take $f \in $$B_1^{d_1}(0)  \rightarrow ||f||_1 < 1$  then I want an $\epsilon$ neighbourhood around $f$ with respect to infinity norm that lies inside this ball

let $r= 1 - ||f||_\infty$

Then $B_{r}^{d_\infty} (f) \subseteq B_1^{d_1}(0)$ because if

$x\in B_{r}^{d_\infty}  \rightarrow ||x-f ||_\infty < r( = 1 - ||f||_\infty )\rightarrow ||x||_\infty = ||x-f + f||_\infty \leq ||x-f||_\infty + ||f||_\infty < 1  $

So is this argument good?

for the other part:

$0 \in B_{1}^{\infty}(0)$

Suppose there exists $\epsilon > 0 $ such that $B_{\epsilon}^{d_1}(0)\subseteq B_1^{\infty }(0)$

consider the function $f$ whose graph forms the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (\epsilon,0), (\epsilon/2,1.2)$

then $ ||f||_1$ equals area of this triangle = $0.6\epsilon < \epsilon $ so $f\in B_{\epsilon}^{d_1}(0)$ but $||f||_\infty = 1.2 > 1$ so $f\notin B_1^{\infty}(0)$

so there cannot exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}^{d_1}(0)\subseteq B_1^{\infty }(0)$ so not open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f \in B_1^{d_1}(0)$, which means that $f$ is continuous and $I = \int \vert f \vert < 1$ and denote $r = \frac{1-I}{2}$. For $g \in B_r^{d_\infty}(f)$, we have

$$\int \vert g \vert \le \int \vert f \vert + \int \vert g-f \vert = \int \vert f \vert + \Vert g-f \Vert_\infty \le I + r < 1.$$

That proves that for any $f \in B_1^{d_1}(0)$, we can find an open ball for $d_\infty$ centered on $f$ and included in$f \in B_1^{d_1}(0)$. Therefore $B_1^{d_1}(0)$ is open in $(\mathcal C[0,1], d_\infty)$.

Now consider for all $n \in \mathbb N$

$$g_n(x)=
\begin{cases}
1-nx & 0 \le x \le 1/n\\
0 & 1/n \le x \le 1
\end{cases}
$$
We have $d_1(0,g_n) = \int \vert g_n \vert = 1/n$ and $d_\infty(0,g_n) = 1$. As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d_1(0,g_n) = 0$, it is impossible to find an open ball for $d_1$ centered on $0$ and included in $B_1^{d_\infty}(0)$. Proving that $B_1^{d_\infty}(0)$ is not open in $(\mathcal C[0,1], d_1)$.

Comment: do you see any flaw in my method? I basically showed $||x||_1 \leq ||x||_\infty <1$ so $x\in B_1^{d_1} (0)$

Comment: @Abhay The flaw I see is that you're not using the norm $\Vert f \Vert_1=\int \vert f \vert$ in your *proof*. And that should be when you speak of $B_1^{d_1}(0)$.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I just revisited and observed I need to use the norm $1$ inside norm $1$ unit ball

Comment: The reason I think I was able to get the answer is because $1-||f||_\infty \leq 1-||f||_1$ anyway so I was safe. Do you agree? But it is a nice concept to clear that I should be using the same norm as that of the ball.

Comment: I agree with your inequality indeed.

Comment: also let me know if this counter examples seems ok to you

Comment: @Abhay How do you define $f_\epsilon$ for $x \ge \epsilon$? If is vanishing for those values, then I do agree!

Comment: yes vanishing indeed. Basically above, I defined only on $[0,\epsilon]$ and $ 0$ everywhere else